# .get request always success status

Tags: php, jquery, get, request

I have to get the content of page demo_test.php, but the status is always = success, while "data" print the code of the index main and then not of demo_test.php.

Also if I put an inexistent address.php, status is **always = success.**

```
 $.get("demo_test.php",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + status);
 });
```

Why ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that you haven't looked at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Yes, I read! What is the problem ? THanks

Comment: adding it as an answer, one second. you specifically should've looked at the example midway down the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get( "demo_test.php", function(data) {
  alert( "Data: "+data );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "We failed" );
 });
```